# how to add react-native-image-marker package manually to android MainApplication getPackages() method

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I try to add react-native-image-marker package to getPackages method of MainApplication.java file, I have tried :

```
import import com.jimmydaddy.imagemarker;

 @Override
      protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
        List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
     
        packages.add(new imagemarker());
        return packages;
      }
```

it keep firing an erro saying :

> Error: The package 'react-native-image-marker' doesn't seem to be
> linked

could you please accept to correct my code